# Help with php regex for limiting allowed characters 

Tags: php, regex

I'm working in php and want to set some rules for a submitted text field. I want to allow letters, numbers, spaces, and the symbols `# ' , -`

This is what I have:

```
/^(a-z,0-9+# )+$/i
```

That seems to work but when I add the `'` or `-` symbols I get errors.

Comment: Do you want to allow the `+` symbol or not? Can't quite tell from your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there. What you're looking for is called [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). These are denoted by the use of square brackets. For example

```
/^[-a-z0-9+#,' ]+$/i
```

To include the hyphen character, it needs to be the first or last character in the class.

#### Edit

As you want to include the single quote and you're using PHP where regular expressions must be represented as strings, be careful with how you quote the pattern. In this case, you can use either of

```
$pattern = "/^[-a-z0-9+#,' ]+\$/i"; // or
$pattern = '/^[-a-z0-9+#,\' ]+$/i';
```

Comment: Rather: `/^[-a-z0-9\+#, ]+$/i` (notice `i` at the end) or `/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\+#, ]+$/`

Comment: @Tradeck Oops, forgot the case insensitivity flag. Added that and the single quote. You don't need to escape `+` in a character class either

Comment: [Don't forget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181689/help-with-regex/6181743#6181743) about the trailing `\n` that is possible with `$`. :D

Comment: @Phil, thank you! I was having trouble with the single quote but decided not to allow it at all, to avoid sql injections. Good to know nonetheless! :)

Comment: @CyberJunkie Use prepared statements and bound parameters instead of filtering bad characters out of SQL values

Comment: @alex You are totally correct. I'll leave my answer as-is, yours is the correct one

Comment: @Phil Unless of course the OP doesn't mind the trailing `\n` :)

Comment: @phil, I noticed that the `+` symbol also needs to escaped. I checked in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and `+` alone is `match previous token 1 more time`. `\+` is just the + symbol.

Comment: @CyberJunkie The documentation says otherwise. Works fine in my test too. The plus sign does not need to be escaped in a character class

Answer (score 2):

You should use a character class - `[a-zA-Z0-9 #',-]`

Note that `-` should be used first or last or escaped otherwise it gets treated as denoting a range and you will get errors

Answer (score 2):

> I want to allow letters, numbers, spaces, and the symbols `#`, `'`, `,` and `-`.

Use this regex...

```
/^[-a-zA-Z\d ',#]+\z/
```

Note the `\z`. If you use `$`, you are allowing a trailing `\n`. [CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tw27X3i).

Ensure to escape the `'` if you are using `'` as your string delimiter.

Comment: sorry I'm confused about the `\z` and `$`. How am I allowing a line break in the text field?

Comment: @CyberJunkie `$` matches either the end of the string or before a trailing `\n`. `\z` *always* matches at the end of the string.

Comment: @CyberJunkie Well they don't match your constraint that I quoted above.

Answer (score 1):

Please use `/^[a-z,0-9+\#\-,\s]+$/i`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
/^[-a-z0-9,# ']+$/i
```