# Regular expression to maintain characters a-zA-Z0-9$!.,

Tags: php, regex

May I know how to approve only letters a-z, A-Z and digits 0-9 and special character $!., with regular expression in php?

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9$!\.\,]{1,100}$/", $name);
```

What goes wrong here?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: It's a simple character class, pretty much as you have it. Where's your hurdle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with php regex for limiting allowed characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181689/help-with-php-regex-for-limiting-allowed-characters)

Comment: preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9$!\.\,]{1,100}$/", $name); what goes wrong here?

Comment: @davidlee: No code in comments please. Use the edit link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11022137/edit

Comment: * See also [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there) and [Online regex testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282/regex-testing) for some helpful tools, or [RegExp.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) for a nicer tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Off of the top of my head

```
if (preg_match('/^[^a-z\d\$!\.,]$/i', $string)){
     // fail
}
```

Comment: (In case you don't see the difference, davidlee: escape the ``$``.)  I don't think the wildcard ``.`` needs to be escaped though.